# Rails 3 displaying tasks from partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Tasks belongs to different models but are always assigned to a company and/or a user.  I am trying to narrow what gets displayed by grouping them by there due_at date without doing to many queries.

Have a application helper

```
def current_tasks
  if user_signed_in? && !current_company.blank?
    @tasks = Task.where("assigned_company = ? OR assigned_to = ?", current_company, current_user)
    @current_tasks = @tasks
  else
    @current_tasks = nil
  end
end
```

Then in my Main view I have

```
<%= render :partial => "common/tasks_show", :locals => { :tasks => current_tasks }%>
```

My problem is that in my task class I have what you see below.  I have the same as a scope just named `due_today`.  when I try `current_tasks.due_today` it works if I try `current_tasks.select_due_today` I get a `undefined method "select_due_tomorrow" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x66a7ee8>`

```
def select_due_today
   self.to_a.select{|task|task.due_at < Time.now.midnight || !task.due_at.blank?}
end
```

Comment: Where is `select due tomorrow` defined and what is the code for it?

Comment: Sorry, it is in my class Task model.  Trying to use the code to not query sql again.  I already got all the tasks once in the current_tasks.  Now trying to narrow what gets displayed where.

Comment: You must be leaving something out of your question, because given what you have there's absolutely no reason `select_due_tomorrow` should be being called when you do `current_tasks.select_due_today`. Your `current_tasks` helper also violates MVC.

Comment: can you elaborate on how it violates MVC?  Goal is to show tasks in different views.

Comment: You have a method something like `current_tasks_for(user)` in your Task model, rather than having a query in a helper.

Comment: So something in the lines of :locals => { :tasks => Task.current_tasks_for(user, company) }.  I though it was not good practice to do a find in a view.

Comment: Why not put it in a variable in the controller and then pass that to the partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `current_tasks.select_due_today` then it'll have to be a class method, something like this (translating your Ruby into SQL):

```
def self.select_due_today
  select( 'due_at < ? OR due_at IS NOT NULL', Time.now.midnight )
end
```

Or, you could have pretty much the same thing as a scope - but put it in a lambda so that `Time.now.midnight` is called when you call the scope, not when you define it.

[edited to switch `IS NULL` to `IS NOT NULL` - this mirrors the Ruby in the question, but makes no sense because it will negate the left of the `OR`s meaning]

Comment: So named scopes it is.  Was trying to avoid having to do multiple calls for due_today, tomm, etc.